# Count the number of times a string appears in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that returns a list with the number of times a name appears in a file.  I have two helper functions that go through the file and get two lists, one with all the names and then another with all the unique names.  I want to use the unique names and compare them to all the names and count the number of times the name unique name appears in the all names list.

```py
    #call getAllPeople helper function to get list
    allName=getAllPeople(fileName)
    #call getUniquePeople from helper function to get comparison
    uniNam=getUniquePeople(fileName)
    #give empty list
    namNum=[]
    #initiate counter
    count=0
    #iterate through list
    for name in allName:
        #if name is in getUniquePeople(fileName)
        if name in uniNam:
            #add to count
            count = count+1

            return count
```

I am looking for:

```
['bob:4', 'jane:4', 'pam:2', 'batman:1']
```

In playing with it with:

```py
#give empty list 
namCount=[] 
#initiate counter 
count=0 
#iterate through list 
for name in range(len(allName)): 
    #if name is in getUniquePeople(fileName) 
    if name in uniNam: 
    #add to count 
    count = count+1 
    #append namCount with 
    namCount.append(name +':'+str(count)) 
    return namCount
```

I am getting nothing in return

Comment: You should look into how dictionaries work in python, they will make this problem almost trivial https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1):

As @Hoog commented, dictionaries are a much better fit for this problem.

```
# make a new empty dictionary
results = {}

for name in allName:
    if name in uniNam:
        # if name is already in the results dictionary, add 1 to its count
        if name in results:
            results[name] = results[name] + 1
        # otherwise create a new name in the dictionary with a count of 1
        else:
            results[name] = 1

{'bob': 4, 'jane': 4, 'pam': 2}
```

EDIT -- If you absolutely have to use just lists:

```
# make new lists for holding names and counts
names = []
name_counts = []

for name in allName:
    if name in uniNam:
        # if name is already in our list, add 1 to the the corresponding entry in the name_counts list
        if name in names:
            position = names.index(name)
            name_counts[position] = name_counts[position] + 1
        # otherwise add this name to our lists with a count of 1
        else:
            names.append(name)
            name_counts.append(1)

# now combine our two lists into the final result
final_list = []
for position in range(len(names)):
    final_list.append(names[position] + ':' + str(name_counts[position]))
```

Comment: is there a way to do that with out doing the dictionary?  The instructor for the class doesn't want us to use that due to not covering it in class.

Comment: I see what your doing, and thank you. In playing with it with:
```python
    #give empty list
    namCount=[]
    #initiate counter
    count=0
    #iterate through list
    for name in range(len(allName)):
        #if name is in getUniquePeople(fileName)
        if name in uniNam:
            #add to count
            count = count+1
            #append namCount with 
            namCount.append(name +':'+str(count))            
            return namCount
```
I am getting nothing in return

Comment: It's hard to read code in a comment like this.  Please update your original question with the new code.

Comment: I tried what you said John, but it is telling me that one of the names in the list is not there at the position=names.index(name) line

Comment: I don't see how that's possible, as that line is only executed when `if name in names` is true, so it _must_ be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Counter to achieve this.

```
from collections import Counter
names = ['John G.', 'Mark T.', 'Brian M.', 'Mark T.', 'Kit H.'] # All names
c = Counter(names)
print(c)

Output:
Counter({'Mark T.': 2, 'John G.': 1, 'Brian M.': 1, 'Kit H.': 1})
```

Comment: I am trying to use this algorithmicaly with out using functions like counter.